# Can xpath select from one element to a different type of element?

Tags: xpath

brand new to xpath, so maybe just don't know the terminology to search properly.

I want to grab from the start of a div with a certain id, to the end of a paragraph with a certain id.  Note that I only want to select part of the div.

```
<body>
<div id="meaninglessPreamble">Do not get this data.</div>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="grabThis">good stuff</div>
<p id="grabThisToo">more good stuff</p>
<p id="endHere"/>
<p id="leaveMeOutOfThis">Unwanted Junk</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you need to select? Do you want to select the entire nodes or the text inside the attributes and elements?

Comment: please provide sample output you'd expect from html above

Comment: Depending on how you are going to use the data, it might be simpler to extract several small bits with separate expressions. For example `//div[3]/@id` will give you `grabThis` while `//div[3]` will give you the full `<div>` node. And you can concatenate everything in one string.

Comment: @helderdarocha turned out OP already gave *implicit* sample. It seems that he wants elements starting from `<div id="grabThis">` to `<p id="endHere>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More general approach, you can try using following-sibling and preceding-sibling to select a range of elements by id attribute.

```
/body/div[@id='wrapper']/*
        [
            (preceding-sibling::*[@id='grabThis'] or @id='grabThis')
                and
            (following-sibling::*[@id='endHere'] or @id='endHere')
        ]
```

Above example demonstrates selecting all child elements of `<div id="wrapper">`, starting from element with `id="grabThis"` to element with `id="endHere"` inclusively. If you want it to select exclusively (exclude the limiting elements), simply remove the `or @id='...'` part.

Answer (score 0):

One way to select those two elements, by selecting the children of the div who's @id is equal to "wrapper" and their following-sibling is a p element that has an @id equal to "endHere":

```
/body/div[@id='wrapper']/*[following-sibling::p[@id='endHere']]
```